# Scala packages and importing

Tags: scala

I have my very first scala program HelloWorld.scala which is located in `~/home/Jacobian/Projects/core/scala/` folder. Now I want to test the concept of packages and see how they can be imported/used. This is the code I have:

```
package Projects.core.scala

class HelloWorld{
    private[scala] var greeting: String = "Hello from package"
}
```

That is. As you can see, I call my package `Projects.core.scala` just to reflect that I'm somewhere in `/...very_long_path/Projects/core/scala/`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the problem is, when I compile my program with `$ scalac HelloWorld.scala` I get an error message:

> error: '{' expected but ';' found

It's a funny error message, because I have no `';'` in my code. If someone can show what I'm doing wrong, that would be great. But it would be even more useful, if someone could also share how this class HelloWorld wrapped in some arbitrary package (not necessary compatible with folders structure) can be imported. (PS. I'm reading Horstman book on Scala, but I can not figure out what can I do when it comes to a real world program and not to abstract concepts that are quite easy to understand)

**FULL ERROR MESSAGE:**

> HelloWorld.scala:9: error: '{' expected but ';' found
>
> class HelloWorld{
>
> ^ one error found

This error message pops up, when there are no parantheses and if I add

```
package Projects.core.scala {
    class HelloWorld { ...
```

then the error goes away.

**Importing issue**

Now that I've wrapped `class HelloWorld` with parantheses and compiled the program, I see that there appeared some folder structure. So, it seems like now it should be quite easy to import the class and this is how I try to do that:

```
import Projects.core.scala.HelloWorld

object Test{
     def main(args: Array[String]){
         println("Hello from Test")
     }
}
```

`Test.scala` is located right in the same folder where `HelloWorld.scala` and in this very folder I see Projects/core/scala/HelloWorld.class and other compiled files. However, when I try to compile now `Test.scala`, I get another error message:

> Test.scala:3:error not found: object Projects

It is again very interesting - why it is trying to find an object, when I want it to import a class? And why does not it import this class? What other woodoo magic should take place?

**File tree structure**

```
HelloWorld.scala
Test.scala
Projects/core/scala/HelloWorld.class
```

And this is how `Test.scala` looks like:

```
import Projects.core.scala.HelloWorld._

object Test{
   def main(args: Array[String]){
        println("Hello from test")
   }
}
```

I also tried `import Projects.core.scala.HelloWorld` and import `Projects.core.scala._`, but none of them work. I always get an error message:

> error: not found: object Projects

**EDIT**

I added full path to Projects/core/scala/ to the CLASSPATH, but it does not help. Still, compiler is unable to import my custom class. I find it really frustrating, cos in `Python` or other languages that I know, it will take me a couple of second to do the trick, here I have to spend hours on such a miserable task - just importing a class. Gosh!

Comment: It seems like it should be `package Projects.core.scala { ... class HelloWorld {...} }`, though in a book that I read, there are no parantheses.

Comment: Add full error message that produced by `$ scalac HelloWorld.scala`

Comment: @Anton. I made an update.

Comment: And this error happens contrary to Chapter 7 of Horstman book.

Comment: Try to remove `Projects` word and remove curly braces from `package` statement and recompile this class

Comment: I tried it and it does not help.

Comment: Ok man I don't know how to explain it. May I suggest you to pick up this [guide](https://goo.gl/T03U4U) or read [Scala Cookbook](http://goo.gl/5Ijm2K). Hope with it you will figure out your issue.

Comment: Thank you, Anton. Although, I find it rather frustrating that to solve some really basic teene-weeny tasks, you first have to read tons of literature, before you find a magic words combination, that will work.

Comment: For you last updates. `Projects.core.scala` it is not Scala packages. If it will be are packages your `Test` object should have `package Projects.core.scala` statement on the top of file. Are your using any IDE right now ?

Comment: If it is not Scala package, what was then created automatically by `$ scalac HelloWorld.scala` and what are those folders `Projects/core/scala/...` with numerous files mean?

Comment: I'm not using any IDE right now, just a text editor. And I hope that I do not need to use any monstrous IDE to write a HelloWorld program and to import some simplest external class to the current class.

Comment: 1. It should compile without problems: http://scastie.org/12596
2. If you are running `scalac` from the same directory `HelloWorld.scala` and `Test.scala` are in, it should work (unless you have `CLASSPATH` environment variable set). If it doesn't, there _might_ be something wrong with the Scala install. You can try to be more explicit and give the directory in `-classpath` option. 3. While you certainly don't need an IDE, I'd very much recommend using a build system, [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Hello.html) in Scala's case for anything less trivial.

Comment: Passing both files to `scalac` should work as well.

Comment: 1. I know that it should, but it does not. 2 I explicitely set `CLASSPATH` with `$ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:full_path_to_Projects/core/scala`, but again it does not help. It seems like there should be some black mantra that can make it all work,

Comment: using sbt `run` command also does not help. It results in an error message` class HelloWorld exists, but it has no companion object`. I do not know what all this magic words may mean in such a trivial situation

Comment: 1. You need `compile` instead of `run`; 2. It means that `Test` did find `HelloWorld`, but `import Projects.core.scala.HelloWorld._` means to import either all classes/traits/etc. of the _package_ `Projects.core.scala.HelloWorld` or all members of the _object_ `Projects.core.scala.HelloWorld` and `scalac` guesses you mean the second because a class with this name exists. Switch to either `Projects.core.scala.HelloWorld` or `Projects.core.scala._` and it should finally work.